# Create an event indicator for multiple outcomes in panel data using R

Tags: r, events, dplyr, panel

I have panel data Z organized by id and year (repeated observations of variable X per id). The variable X can take 3 values (e.g. 0,1,2). I would like to create another variable that captures events of change in X from 0 to 1 or 2. I am only interested in shifts from 0 to any other value. When there is no such change from t-1 to t in X the new variable would take a value of 0. When there is a change in X from 0 to 1 the new variable would take 1, if there is a change from 0 to 2 the new variable would take 2.

Comment: Or at least how the output should look like. diff(x), where x is a vector could be your friend. You can then you an ifelse statement to restrict.

Answer (score 0):

May be we need

```
library(dplyr)
ifelse(v1 == 0, pmax(v1, lead(v1, default = -1)), v1)
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(1234)
# set a seed
datas = sample(size = 100,0:2,replace=TRUE)
# calculate the differences
# ad an NA as there is no difference for t-1==0
diffdatas <- c(NA,diff(datas))
#use ifelse for conditional events
cond_diff <- ifelse(datas==0,diffdatas,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way with base R -

```
set.seed(2)
x <- sample(c(0,1,2), 10, replace = T, prob = c(3,1,1))

x
[1] 0 2 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0

ifelse(x + c(0, x[-length(x)]) == x, x, 0)

[1] 0 2 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
```